# Word(s) to describe persons that leave a company and have a lot of information in their heads that is lost

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What would you call the situation/a person with a lot of knowledge about a company that leaves the company, and the information is no longer available because the person left?

I'd like to use the word(s) I'm looking for in a sales pitch like this: "Stop being affected by <situation/persons>!"

E.g. a senior engineer who's been with the company since the early days and knows a lot of things that are not documented and all the other engineers rely on them for context?

Comment: There's a related question on "Tribal Knowledge" that provides a fairly comprehensive overview of options. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/etymology-ubiquity-and-synonyms-of-the-phrase-tribal-knowledge

Comment: Is is a form of brain drain from turnover?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Brain drain, or human capital flight is related, but the question asks for a lot of knowledge about the company, while brain drain is more about intellectual or technical capabilities.

Comment: “Certaine it is, that when a great learned man (who is long in making) dieth, much learning dieth with him.” –Edward Coke

Comment: Seems an odd thing to say. If they've lost such a colleague they can't but help being affected by it. The firm should have done something to ensure that the knowledge was passed on before the engineer retired. Probably thought it cheaper to employ someone younger.

Comment: Thanks, "Trial Knowledge" was the phrase I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

> "Stop being affected by the loss of **institutional knowledge**!"

The term is a littler broader, but includes knowledge held by employees and former employees:

**institutional knowledge** (n.)

> **Institutional knowledge is the combination of experiences, processes,
> data, expertise, values, and information possessed by company
> employees. It can span decades and comprise crucial trends, projects,
> perspectives and that define a company’s history.**
>
> Institutional knowledge takes many forms. Some of it is intentionally
> developed while other information is learned on the job and possibly
> even intuitive. The International Federation of Library Associations
> and Institutions offers the following categories for **institutional
> knowledge**:
>
> **Explicit/tangible:** documents, records, reports, etc. that can be
> viewed, stored, and transferred
>
> **Implicit/intangible:** personal
> anecdotes and context, skills, and intuition that can be transferred
> person to person through mentorship or training
>
> Both forms of institutional knowledge provide value, so the most
> successful companies find a way to manage both. [eduflow](https://www.eduflow.com/blog/institutional-knowledge-why-it-matters-and-how-to-tap-into-it)

> "**Institutional Knowledge: When employees leave, what do we lose?**"
>
> When employees leave a job, of their own volition or not, employers
> lose the **institutional knowledge** or history that they take with
> them, and many organizations lack sufficient transfer programs to stem
> the loss.
>
> Andrew M. Peña; at [higherEdJobs](https://www.higheredjobs.com/articles/articleDisplay.cfm?id=468) (2013)

Comment: One also sees the similar terms "corporate memory" or "[organizational memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_memory)."

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "firm-specific knowledge" could be useful here. For example, "We are struggling to replace workers with a high level of firm-specific knowledge."

"Firm-specific knowledge" conveys the idea that the knowledge lost is specific to a particular institution (in this case, the company) rather than more general knowledge.

Whilst the term may seem a bit clunky for everday conversation, it is used extensively in the academic literature on economic theories of the firm.

Comment: Sorry, but "firm-specific" is horrible. Try expressing yourself in simple straightforward English, e.g. "We are finding it difficult to replace workers who had long experience of the company".

Comment: @David "Firm-specific" is perfectly fine. There might be a better alternative, but *horrible* is an overstatement, and "workers who had long experience of the company" is simply wrong. A more natural phrase would be "workers who have worked at the company for a long time" or "workers who have many years of experience at the company."